# How to use getorientation and getrotation matrix to calculate pitch,roll

Tags: android, device-orientation, pitch

I want to get roll and pitch values to detect tilt of device in 4 directions.
I want to use getorientation and getrotation matrix to do it.
How can i do it?
Even links would be helpful.

Comment: What device? What language or libraries are you using? This question needs more details.

Comment: I want it to work on as many devices as possible. I am new to android developing.Using Java for Android application.

Comment: Tagged your question android so it gets attention from the right people...

Answer (score -1):

If a **link** is all you want, try reading this section in it's entirety:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html#sensors-pos-orient

**You should focus on the 4th paragraph** (the one starting with "The orientation sensor derives[...]").

Comment: I already read that.I want to know how to use getRotationMatrix() method in conjunction with the getOrientation() method to compute orientation values.